# How to test if UIAlertView is shown on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertview

I'm writing Unit tests for my app and there seems to be a problem with getting shown UIAlertView.

On iOS 7, this used to work:

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)]
```

but this doesn't work on iOS 8.

Is there a way visible UIAlertView can be retrieved on iOS 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIAlertView and UIActionSheet is combined in a class called UIAlertController in ios8. Kindly check the Apple Document

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

> A UIAlertController object displays an alert message to the user. This
>   class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes for
>   displaying alerts. After configuring the alert controller with the
>   actions and style you want, present it using the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method.

Comment: Ah I see. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it because iOS 8 use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView.

[Apple Developers Library "UIAlertController"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)